# haskell comprehension list, compare string with list and create string list with values, from list

Tags: haskell

I am new haskell. I want always check the first element from the string and compare the string with Char value from the list. So firstly I will compare "H" with 'E', then "H" with 'F', then "H" with 'G', and last "H" with 'H'. And if "H" = 'H' so I want add to my output string value of list element, in my case for 'H' it is "GG". But If all four are not equal so I want add to list current character in my case "A".
So I want my output to look like this ["GG","A","GG","A"]
Do you know some solution ?

My code:

```
findc :: String -> [(Char, String)] -> [String]
findc str list = 
  let filtered = [ if inputChar `elem` [(str !! num)] then decodedValue else if inputChar /= (str !! num) then [(str !! num)] else [] | num<-[0..(length str)-1],(inputChar,decodedValue) <- list]
  in  filtered
```

input:

```
findc "HAHA" [('E', "AB"), ('F', "CD"), ('G', "EF"), ('H', "GG")]
```

bad output:

```
["H","H","H","GG","A","A","A","A","H","H","H","GG","A","A","A","A"]
```

Comment: if I've understood your task correctly, I think you will find [lookup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) invaluable. You probably want to use it in connection with both [fromMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) and [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) while remembering that a String in Haskell is just a list of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is using a list comprehension with effectively nested loops. It loops over the indices of the string *and* then over the elements in the list of tuples you've passed in. Both contain 4 elements, so it's natural that your list comprehension iterates 16 times and you end up with 16 elements in your incorrect output.

### A simpler, correct approach

`[(Char, String)]` describes a lookup table.

Fortunately, Haskell gives us the `lookup` function.

```
:ghci> :t lookup
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
ghci> tbl = [('E', "AB"), ('F', "CD"), ('G', "EF"), ('H', "GG")]
ghci> lookup 'H' tbl
Just "GG"
ghci> lookup 'A' tbl
Nothing
```

Now, you just need to map this to your string in a list comprehension, handling the `Just` case differently from the `Nothing` case.

```
ghci> [case lookup ch tbl of {Just s -> ...; Nothing -> ...} | ch <- "HAHA"]
["GG","A","GG","A"]
```

### Using Data.Maybe.maybe

Unsurprisingly the Data.Maybe library has fucntions for dealing with `Maybe` values like those returned by `lookup`.

```
case expr1 of { Just x -> expr2; Nothing -> expr3 }
```

Can be expressed as:

```
maybe expr3 (\x -> expr2) expr1
```

So we can write:

```
ghci> [maybe ... ... $ lookup ch tbl | ch <- "HAHA"]
["GG","A","GG","A"]
```

Comment: When I past this code : ghci> [case lookup ch tbl of {Just s -> ...; Nothing -> ...} | ch <- "HAHA"] into my terminal it report an error. <interactive>:22:35: error: parse error on input ‘...’

Comment: I didn't want to hand you a totally complete solution. The `...` parts need to be filled in by you.

Comment: OK, I will try to figure it out. Thanks